# Como colocar um div sobreposto à um video embed em fullscreen?

Tags: html, css, fullscreen, embed

Como posso fazer, para ter um div sobreposto à um video embedado do youtube?
Queria que no caso abaixo, o div `id="banner"` ficasse na frente do video quando ele estiver em fullscreen:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oQ4xTJ0sZsM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="banner" style="background:#000;color:#fff;width:300px;height:250px;z-index:999;position:fixed;top:5px;left:5px;">
    TESTE DIV
</div>
```

Comment: Se não me engano o browser não deixa fazer isso por uma questão de segurando, tem até um nome para isso chama `clickjacking` e vc acha material a vontade sobre isso no Google. Não sei se vc vai achar algo exatamente sobre essa prática com iFrame, mas basicamente é colocar um btn falso sobre algo que parece verdadeiro. Muitas vezes inclusive esse btn falso tem opacity:0, e fica sobre o botão original do iframe, por isso o browser não deixa

Comment: uhnn, entendi, vou pesquisar sobre isso, vlw

Comment: Outra coisa que eu reparei, dentro desse iframe tem 2 scripts, se vc desabilitar o Script na página e tentar colocar o vídeo em fullscrean não vai funcionar, o que significa que ao clicar no btn de fullscrean vc tb está rodando um script que pode está justamente tratando disso